# Wordpress Image Upload - 403 with Cloudfront Enabled

Tags: images, cdn

I have a WP instance set up on AWS Lightsail.  I've set up Cloudfront in front of it, pretty much following the steps set out at https://itnext.io/how-configure-a-wordpress-site-with-lightsail-using-cloudfront-and-route-53-c52ce5719b82.

Everything seems to work well, apart from image upload within WordPress,  whenever I try to upload an image I get an error within the WP app

[image]

Looking at the network requests I can see a 403 returned with an `X-Cache` value of `Error from cloudfront`.

[image]

I have a number of CF behaviours set up as below:

[image]

with the relevant behaviour IMHO being the `wp-admin` one

[image]

My original assumption was that I hadn't configured the behaviour to allow `POST` or that there was some `HTTPS` issue, however this seems to be fine from what I can see.

Can anyone offer any advice on what might be going on here?